# Why when I change position about the axis(x, y), my figure change shape like in picture below?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I change position about the axis(x, y), my figure change shape like in picture below. How can I fix it? I'm using `Three.js`.

```
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 2000 );
camera.position.set(0,0,20);
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2 );
document.getElementById('gameWindow').appendChild( renderer.domElement );
const canvas = renderer.domElement;
const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 20, 20 ), material );
const cube1 = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry( 2, 20, 20 ), material );
scene.add(cube, cube1);
cube.position.x=20;
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

[image]

Comment: What you see is the typical effect of using a perspective camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to maintain the shape of your figure when you change the position, you'll need to switch to an orthographic projection.

To do so in `three.js` you'll need to replace your `PerspectiveCamera` with an `OrthographicCamera`.

[Here's a link to the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=ortho#api/en/cameras/OrthographicCamera) that'll help you.